# matlab column and row element summation using a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, matrix, sum

I need to wire an algorithm for class without using any Matlab functions and using for and while loops, that gives me two new vectors one with the sum of elements of each column, and another with the sum of elements in each row and compares them.

I got this far based on a similar code I wrote in python:

```
A = input('Matrix Input: '); 
[m, n] = size(A);

for i = 1:m;
    sumRow = zeros(1,m);
    for j = 1:n;
        sumRow = sumRow + A(i,j);
    end;
end;
for i = 1:n;
    sumCol = zeros(1,n);
    for j = 1:m;
        sumCol = sumCol + A(j,i);
    end;
end;
A %#ok<NOPTS>
sumRow %#ok<NOPTS>
sumCol %#ok<NOPTS>
```

but in Matlab I can only get to to store in the new vectors the sum of the elements in the last row and last column, while in python I get vectors with one element for each row or column.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning to `sumRow` properly, and you are overwriting with a zero vector each time round the loop.  Your code should look like this:

```
sumRow = zeros(1,m);
for i = 1:m;
    for j = 1:n;
        sumRow(i) = sumRow(i) + A(i,j);
    end;
end;

sumCol = zeros(1,n);
for i = 1:n;

    for j = 1:m;
        sumCol(j) = sumCol(j) + A(j,i);
    end;
end;
```

This way, you create `sumRow` *outside* the loop, and the `i`th element of sumRow will be the sum of all the columns in the row.

Comment: thanks, though now i get an error message "Attempted to access sumRow(2); index out of bounds because numel(sumRow)=1."

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly?  I've just tested it without any problems.  That error can never happen since `i` goes from `1` to `m`, and `sumRow` is initialised as length `m`.

Comment: Not sure what was wrong, after that I got some other error as both vectors were the same, but I modified it to check rows for the transpose of A in the second, and it worked. Thanks a lot!